# Validations for input tag HTML

Tags: html

Set validation for making user unable to enter value more than 5000 in input tag.
Decimals can be accepted but over all value should be less than 5000.
After 5000 the tag should be editable but should not take any number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for solving your query, I have used jquery here you can even use pure Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input").keyup(function(){
 var value=$("input").val();
if(value>5000){
  $("input").val("");
}
});
});
```

Look at the bin for more info: https://jsbin.com/zatidojixu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It automatically does the input to blank if the user enters more than 5000 try it out

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<input type="number" max="5000">
```

Comment: i dont have to set the length .... it has to be like no one can enter values greater than 5000 .. hew can enter 0.1111 but cant enter more than 5000 (i.e 5000.1 or 5001 cant be entered)

Comment: Sorry miss interpreted your question. I've updated the code above.